# How may I prevent CTRL+R moving focus to output window?

Tags: processing, processing-ide

How may I prevent CTRL+R in the program editing window moving the focus to the output window each time?

(This does completely describe the problem.)

Comment: Why do you want this? What exactly are you trying to do? You might mention that you're talking about the Processing editor, since right now people have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: "Why do you want this?" So I don't have to restore focus before continuing to edit the program. "You might mention that you're talking about the Processing editor" Done. I was unaware there is anywhere else that CTRL+R moves the focus to the output window.

Comment: Most people have never used the Processing editor (which is why you're getting downvotes and closevotes) and have no idea what ctrl+R normally does or what you'd want it to do instead. Best to completely spell it out.

Comment: "Most people have never used the Processing editor (which is why you're getting downvotes and closevotes)" Goodness. Ignorant ignorance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the shortcut of `ctrl+R` running your sketch from the Processing editor, then there isn't a setting to disable that.

However, [Processing is open-source](https://github.com/processing/processing), including the Processing editor. So you're more than welcome to download the source, remove the shortcut yourself, and run that instead.

Similarly, if you want to shift focus of the window back to the editor, there isn't a way to do that from the settings. But you could modify the source to make that happen pretty easily.

Comment: "If you're talking about the shortcut of ctrl+R running your sketch from the Processing editor" No. I'm fine with it doing that. I'm talking about it moving focus.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Please see my third paragraph then.